# Estimate the delay between two signals

Tags: time-series, python, cross-correlation

I have two voltage time series from two sides of a battery with 20 seconds resolution. The signals are non-periodic and `voltage2` is usually half the `voltage`. There are reasons to believe that there may be a *slight* delay in the signals and I wonder how I can estimate it.

Example of the data:

[image: Data example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To estimate the time delay between two signals you can use the cross-correlation (`np.correlate`) between them and find the argmax of the cross-correlation function

$$\tau_{\text{delay}} = \text{argmax }((f * g)(t)),$$

this will estimate the time offset where the signals are best aligned.

Another possible way is to use peak-detection (`scipy.signal.find_peak`) and find matching peaks (e.g. with max or min in each signal or more sophisticated methods) and calculate the offset.